# Windows mobile 5.0 GPS Info recording and imposing on a Map after syncing the data with the server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, gps, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-gps

I am looking for best solution to record the GPS info on my windows mobile 5.0 to the database, and after syncing the windows mobile with the server I am also looking to Impose that data onto a map to show us a path with using those co-ordinates, can some one please help me with some ideas

Thanks
Srikanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are describing is known as GPS Tracker software. There are lots of freeware (http://www.freewarepocketpc.net/ppc-tag-gps.html) and open source projects enabling GPS tracking on Windows Mobile (5) devices. What about this (http://gpstracker.codeplex.com/) for example?

If you intend to write your own software you can simply save location data into a plain text file or in a standard GPX or KML format. Using a database engine like SQL Server compact (SDF files) looks oversized to me.

On the PC side you can use Google MAPs API with the saved data (GPX or KML). See also GPSbabel to convert between these standard formats.

regards

Josef

Answer (score 0):

You can try using sdf files for local storage on the mobile and then push the sdf file up to the server and process it as per your requirements..